# BonitaBPM Community

Tags: bonita

I have built BonitaBPM community 7.3 from source by helping Maven. so, I want to run Bonita portal outside the Bonita Studio. How can I do that by using Apache Tom cat or JBoss server?
any help is acceptable.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you build from source? Just use the deploy, tomcat of wildfly bundle available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the full Bonita BPM project from source you should be able to find the Tomcat and JBoss bundle in `target` folder of the `bonita-distrib` project.

Note that [script to build Bonita BPM 7.4.1](https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/Build-Bonita-BPM/tree/7.4.1) is available.